# Input Sine in a list and performed on every other element

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Im going to make a new [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) called ListeC that every other element is going to have [`Sin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) in it. Like this:

```
12 E^-π, Sin[14 E^-π], 16 E^-π, Sin[18 E^-π], etc
```

This is all the data i have, Thank you for the help

```
ListeA = Range[12, 64, 2]
(* {12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36,
     38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64} *)

ListeB = NRange[ListeA/Exp[π]]
(* NRange[{12 E^-π, 14 E^-π, 16 E^-π, 18 E^-π, 
           20 E^-π, 22 E^-π, 24 E^-π, 26 E^-π, 28 E^-π, 
           30 E^-π, 32 E^-π, 34 E^-π, 36 E^-π, 38 E^-π, 
           40 E^-π, 42 E^-π, 44 E^-π, 46 E^-π, 48 E^-π, 
           50 E^-π, 52 E^-π, 54 E^-π, 56 E^-π, 58 E^-π, 
           60 E^-π, 62 E^-π, 64 E^-π}] *)
```

[image: And how do I make this plot?]

Comment: There is no build in  function `NRange` AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Try [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[Sin[# E^-π] &, ListeA, {2 ;; ;; 2}]
```

> {12, Sin[14 E^-π], 16, Sin[18 E^-π], 20, Sin[22 E^-π], 24,
>     Sin[26 E^-π], 28, Sin[30 E^-π], 32, Sin[34 E^-π], 36, 
>    Sin[38 E^-π], 40, Sin[42 E^-π], 44, Sin[46 E^-π], 48, 
>    Sin[50 E^-π], 52, Sin[54 E^-π], 56, Sin[58 E^-π], 60, 
>    Sin[62 E^-π], 64}

or

```
listC = MapAt[Sin, ListeA  E^-π, {2 ;; ;; 2}]
```

> {12 E^-π, Sin[14 E^-π], 16 E^-π, Sin[18 E^-π], 
>    20 E^-π, Sin[22 E^-π], 24 E^-π, Sin[26 E^-π], 
>    28 E^-π, Sin[30 E^-π], 32 E^-π, Sin[34 E^-π], 
>    36 E^-π, Sin[38 E^-π], 40 E^-π, Sin[42 E^-π], 
>    44 E^-π, Sin[46 E^-π], 48 E^-π, Sin[50 E^-π], 
>    52 E^-π, Sin[54 E^-π], 56 E^-π, Sin[58 E^-π], 
>    60 E^-π, Sin[62 E^-π], 64 E^-π}

**Update:** A way to produce the picture in OP:

Add x-coordinates to `listC`:

```
pairs = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, listC]
```

Group `pairs` based on parity of the x-coordinates:

```
{oddx, evenx} = Select[#@*First][pairs] & /@ {OddQ, EvenQ};
```

Use `ListLinePlot` to show the two lists:

```
ListLinePlot[{oddx, evenx}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get e^-pi on all elements and Sin on every other element?

Comment: @user69571, you can do `Flatten[{# E^-\[Pi], Sin@#2} & @@@ Partition[ListeA, 2]]`

Comment: What in looking for is to combine both this answers to get, 12E^-Pi,Sin[14E^-Pi], 16E^-Pi, Sin[18E^-Pi], etc

Comment: @user69571, `MapAt[Sin, ListeA  E^-π, {2 ;; ;; 2}]` gives that.

Comment: How can I make the photo i just added to the question?

Comment: @user69571, please see the update.